# Select test cases by SpecFlow tag in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: specflow, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

Is it possible to select test cases by SpecFlow tag in Microsoft Test Manager? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags in SpecFlow get translated into TestCategory attributes in the generated code. As far as I know (worked with MTM until a year ago) you can:

1. [Execute tests with MSTest filtered on TestCategory by Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx)
2. [Execute tests with VSTest.Console filtered on TestCategory by TestCaseFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx)
3. [Import test cases into MTM filtered on TestCategory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx)

With the last option, you can create with a bit of creativity a set of testplans with different tests sorted by test category. And I am afraid that is the best you can do without writing your own wrapper around MTM. The TestCategory information is available in TFS, but not exposed to the user in MTM.

**EDIT**

To clear things up after the comment.
Given this feature file:

```
@timtim
Feature: MSTest Tags Test
    In order to get feedback at the right time
    As a test automation specialist
    I want to categorize my tests and run them accordingly

@Jabberwocky @manxome
Scenario: A test with tags
    Given 'twas brillig
    When gyre and gimble in the wabe
    Then all mimsy were the borogoves
```

It gets generated to this code:

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute()]
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DescriptionAttribute("A test with tags")]  
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestPropertyAttribute("FeatureTitle", "MSTest Tags Test")]
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategoryAttribute("timtim")]
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategoryAttribute("Jabberwocky")]
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategoryAttribute("manxome")]
public virtual void ATestWithTags()
{
    TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo("A test with tags", new string[] {
                "Jabberwocky",
                "manxome"});
    #line 8
    this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
    #line 9
    testRunner.Given("\'twas brillig", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
    #line 10
    testRunner.When("gyre and gimble in the wabe", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");
    #line 11
     testRunner.Then("all mimsy were the borogoves", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");
    #line hidden
    this.ScenarioCleanup();
}
```

The scenario becomes a (by MSTest.exe) executable testmethod with three TestCategories: `timtim`, `Jabberwocky` and `manxome`. These are the same testcategories as mentioned in the articles. [Coded UI does have a Test Category property](http://www.matthewbussa.com/2010/09/coded-ui-tests-test-lists-test.html) that can be used to order the tests, but this category boiles down to using [the same `TestCategory` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. The kind of tags I meant was for example an `@Acceptance` on top of a scenario. E.g., `@Acceptance Given ... When ... Then ...` ([see other examples](https://decoupledlogic.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/specflow-tagging/)). The `TestCategory` seems like a special kind of attribute on top of CodedUI tests, not the scenario tags. So unfortunately your suggestion does not seem to work here. If I have more time I will try to find a way, your suggestions did give some inspiration into the capabilities of the tcm tool.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I elaborated more on the test categories, if you look into the `.feature.cs` file yourself, you can see how your own tags become test categories.

Comment: Thank You! I did not make the link, but now I see! :)